# Electric box for kitchen island cabinets

Tags: electrical, kitchens, cabinets

What kind of electrical box can be used in a kitchen island cabinet for a single duplex receptacle, where there is no structural members to attach an electrical box to? Here is a picture of the old box that was there, but I cannot find this kind of box anywhere. The box was inserted from the outside of the cabinet into a very precise sized hole, and the metal bracket attached via a screw in the center put pressure against the inside of the cabinet to keep the box in place.

[image: old electrical box]

The cabinet now has an outer panel attached to it (seen below from *overhead* with the drawer pulled out of the way, white is the panel, brown is the cabinet wall) and so the cabinet wall is thicker, about 1 3/8":

[image: cabinet with panel]

What sort of electrical box can I use to replace the old box given the thickness and the lack of structural support? It needs to be able to clamp FMC. Single 12-2 cable.

Answer (score 5):

The box in your picture is called an "old work box". They still manufacture similar boxes, and they also make old work boxes with even more robust attachment methods. [link to one of the many manufacturers](http://www.hubbell-rtb.com/). [Link to old work bracket.](http://www.hubbell-rtb.com/images/VARIANT/icon/970RAC.jpg)

Comment: I looked at old work boxes, but most will not handle 1 3/8" deep. I'll look into the old work bracket you linked to.

Comment: ahh. that bracket is called an "Old Work Saddle" on that site. thanks for pointing me in that direction. http://www.hubbell-rtb.com/ds-574-switch-box-support-old-work-saddlemounts-switch-boxes-with-plaster-ears-in-hollow-walls-or-ceilings

Comment: @user1663987 - The "more robust" ones that I run across are metal old work boxes with strap clamps on the side, like [this one](http://images.lowes.com/product/converted/785991/785991103373lg.jpg).

Comment: @Comintern, those will accommodate 1 3/8" depth too, plus they are "gangable", you can join them together to create multi-gang old work boxes.

Comment: @Comintern given that I have easy access to both sides, that might be the easiest, as long add I pre-bend the ears and then manually add them inside the cabinet after inserting the box.

Comment: Old work boxes can be modified to accommodate a thicker wall. All you need to do is replace the screws that hold the locking "ears" in with ones long enough for your cabinet.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, I'd just use a [dry-lining box](http://www.screwfix.com/p/appleby-2-gang-47mm-dry-lining-box/45057).

[image]

It is designed for plasterboard walls, and clamps itself to the plasterboard, but no reason you can't do the same using kitchen panels.

Chances are that this wouldn't be allowed in the US, as your electric rules seem to be a *lot* different to ours.

Comment: This is really just the same thing as an old-work box :)

Comment: But knowing the alternative term is helpful. ("Two countries divided by their common language....")